# Regex: split object notation path string with array support

Tags: javascript, regex, javascript-objects

I've got a recursive function to go through an object and take what is needed using path string like `jsonObj.object.item.value`. The idea is to upgrade it somehow to support arrays.

```
const getValue = function(pathVar, obj) {
  obj = obj || x;
  // get very first node and the rest
  let [node, restNodes] = pathVar.split(/\.(.+)/, 2)
  // get interim object
  ret = obj[node];
  if(ret === undefined) return undefined;
  // pass rest of the nodes further with interim object
  if(restNodes) return getValue(restNodes, ret);
  return ret;
};
```

Right now on each iteration simple regexp splits path string like `jsonObj.object.item.value` into `jsonObj` and `object.item.value`

the idea is to add array support here, so I can do transformations like

`car.engine.something` => `car` and `engine.something`
`wheels[2].material.name` => `wheels` and `[2].material.name`
`[2].material.name` => `2` and `material.name`
`car.wheels[4]` => `car` and `wheels[4]`

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: why do you want to re-invent the wheel? there is `_.get` method that does exactly that, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get

Answer (score 1):

You could use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) which will just evaluate the expression. As for a functional approach, use the following.

```
function getValue(path, obj) {
    obj = obj || self; // self is the global window variable
    if( !path )
        return obj;

    let pattern = /(?:\["?)?(\w+)(?:\.|"?])?(.*)/i;

    let [ full, property, rest ] = path.match(pattern);
    return getValue( rest, obj[ property ] );
}

self.obj = { foo: [ 2, {bar: "baz"} ] };
console.log(getValue('obj.foo[1]["bar"]')) // 'baz'
```

Pattern uses four groups. The first is non-capturing and expects a possible `["`this will help match array or object properties. Then we expect a series of alphanumerics which we capture. Then another non capturing group to either close `"]` or match a `.`. Finally we capture the rest to use in the next call.

Again `eval` is capable of all of this.